# Security in rails Active resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

How to use cryptography with XML documents used for rails Active resources? Or, is there any way to garantee security and integrity with comunications through rails Active resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SSL with basic HTTP authentication/API tokens from a database?